# CSS not linking to new HTML pages (Breaks on other pages except for index.html)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

This is pretty much my first go at HTML and CSS. I thought I was getting a hang of it until I added more pages. I wanted each page to have the same top navigation bar format, but when I linked the same CSS Stylesheet to all of my pages it just doesn't want to work? How should I go about fixing this?

Also, somehow my google fonts link did work at first, but once I added in the pages and tried linking the single stylesheet to all the pages, it stopped working completely.

Here's what is going on:

[index.html file code & link href to css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8UOO.jpg)

[Preview of index.html/my homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2TZ3.jpg)

[menu.html file code & link href to the same css stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJDA1.jpg)

[Preview of menu.html/menu page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1eZU.jpg)

[My CSS stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfzEj.jpg)

The preview works with index.html, but when I navigate to the menu page, or contact page I have created through the preview, it completely breaks and doesn't have the navigation bar I created across all the pages at all.

Did I do something wrong here? I tried creating multiple CSS files and gave them different names since each page is going to look different anyways, but kept the html the same across all the other html pages and the css the same.

Comment: please mention (insert in the body) the code that has doubts...

Be objective in your question. It seems that it has several problems regarding several languages.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the css script is working for the index page only is because index.html is the only script that has the right directory to your css script. So the browser can't find the css script as a result. Remember that the other pages are not in the same location as index.html (they are in Pages instead of the root directory). All you would have you do is just change the directory path on the other scripts.

Add this on all your other scripts (excluding index.html):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css"/>
```

It should work after this.

Here is an example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Your actual problem is not knowing how to navigate from one/folder to another. This link below will help you further on how to navigate around folders.

https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/paths-folders/

Don't take out the files from Pages but leave them where they, all you need to do is to change the path to the different files. You'll see how I did on the screenshots above.

If I had more time I would go more in detail but this should be sufficient info for you to solve the problem and understand what mistakes you made. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! So, I changed it to what you put down and it still doesn't work. Do you think it has anything to do with how my pages are linked at all?

Comment: So, I fixed my issue by taking all of my pages out of the Pages folder and changing the class navigation to match with my index.html file's class. I'm unsure if my instructor is going to require us to have a "pages folder". I feel like it is more organized to keep it that way, but it just breaks the whole navigation overall. I'm unsure why that is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited the answer to further answer you question...

Comment: Next time when you ask a question make sure to post you code on here. That will make it easier for people to help find a solution instead of posting screenshots.